# How to create a touch slider with content pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I tried to code this myself or pull in libraries like Tiny Swiper 2, but to no avail.

#### What I want to achieve?

I am coding a PWA (Progressive Web App). It's a good thing when a user has the same experience as a native app. So I wanted to create something [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4HwU_ENXYM):

[image: Gif slider example]

I wanted to create this for a webpage. For mobile devices touch to scroll should even be supported.

#### The Problems?

When I gave up third party plugins I tried on my own again.

Here's an example of what I tried so far in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marcus_derem/qn603h8b/166/)

#### Outstanding problems:

1. In Safari mobile this solution has a very weired navigation feeling.

#### Solved problems:

- It's good because the user can scroll via touch, but they can scroll to the middle of the two pages. He only should be able to swipe between page 1 and 2 and should not be able to stop between the pages.
  **Solution**: `Scroll Snapping`
- The whole webpage scrolls down, that the navigation buttons align to the top, when we navigate with navigation buttons.
  **Solution**: `The main webpage content should have the exactly hight of the screen height. The content of the slider_pages netherless can be larger than the screen width.`
- There is no scroll animation when using the navigation buttons.
  **Solution**: `Add scroll-behavior: smooth; to slider_container`

Comment: I would suggest not to go to a scroll bar. You can instead try tabs structure from any CSS framework. Give [this](https://materializecss.com/tabs.html) a try. Swipeable tabs might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @DumbCoder7 Wow, that is exactly what I need. But is there a way only to use the component? Because my website looks very different right now. Other font, margins, paddings, etc. ...

Comment: You'll have to try Sass

Comment: @DumbCoder7 Thanks, but maybe we can find a self-made solution, without a framework. :)

Comment: yes, of course you can. I just suggested the way I prefer. You can try using vanilla js or JQuery to achieve this too. If you necessarily require that, I can give it a shot. But I'll suggest you to get your hands dirty first. :)